# disable keyup jquery

Tags: jquery, keyup

What I am trying to do is I have a checkbox that will print the two input type the same.. n when unchecked it allows to have different.. here m using the following code... its working when check box is clicked.. what ever the input are given in the first input it places the same but. when i uncheck it still give me when i type some thing in the some. is there any way to disable the keyup function dat m using above..

```
function oncheck(){
var c=$("#ubill").attr('checked');
if(c){
     var value = $("#single").val();
$("#single1").val(value);
$("input").keyup(function () {
var value = $("#single").val();
$("#single1").val(value);


});

}
else {
    var value='';
    $("#single1").val(value);
    // what should be here
}

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This is not very concludent.. Please make us a jsfiddle with what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

```
function stickInputs()
{
    var value = $("#single").val();
    $("#single1").val(value);
}


function oncheck()
{
    var c = $("#ubill").attr('checked');
    if (c)
    {
        var value = $("#single").val();
        $("#single1").val(value);
        //bind a named function
        $("input").keyup(stickInputs);
    }
    else
    {
        var value = '';
        $("#single1").val(value);
        // unbind the function
        $("input").unbind("keyup", stickInputs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the problem at hand. A [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code would be helpful. But in the meantime, I believe it is something along the lines of this that you need, instead of your function:

```
$(function () {
    $("input").keyup(function (e) {
        if($("#ubill").attr('checked')){
            var value = $("#single").val();
            $("#single1").val(value); 
        }
    });
});
```

I moved your if-statement into the keyup-callback. If the `ubill` checkbox is checked, we take the value from one input and place it in the other, otherwise we do nothing.

From the naming of your function, I take it that you call the oncheck function when the checkbox is checked. There is no need to do that. What I do instead is that I wait until the DOM is ready, then we attach a keyup-event listener to the inputs, and then act on every key-up.